# Cakephp - "__" function give me question mark chars (�)

Tags: eclipse, cakephp, utf-8, internationalization

when I have `<?php __('Écoutez votre grand-mère'); ?>` I have an output with question mark chars like: `�coutez votre grand-m�re`. Charset is set to utf-8 in my header. What's wrong ?

[image: Thanks]

Comment: I give a beer to the first one that comes with a valid solution!

Comment: I'm italian. Will you give it to me anyway? :)

Comment: By the way: That character is the [*replacement character* U+FFFD](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22replacement+character%22+U%2BFFFD) used by Unicode encodings to represent invalid byte sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to a colleague a few days ago. He was using Eclipse and he was not saving the file as UTF-8.

Comment: Now that you mention it, the same happened to me once. So yeah, Guillaume, check your IDE.

Comment: Oh no, I found the solution also ans I was about to give a beer to myself :P. In Eclipse: Right click on project >> Properties >> Ressources >> Text file encoding >> Other >> UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Check the consistency of:

- The encoding of the source file containing the message.
- The encoding of the i18n message files, if any.
- The content-encoding in the HTTP response header
- The encoding specified in the HTML header
- The encoding you browser chooses to render the page

Does it work if you do not use __() and just echo the message?

Comment: If I don`t use __() I have the same behavior: é print as a ?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: I don`t have any i18n message, I just use __() so I can later translate in English.

Comment: I tried what you have, in a clean CakePHP installation, and got the correct characters. I do believe it's a browser issue. I got Firefox 3.6 set to Unicode (UTF-8) and got everything allright.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saving your files as UTF-8 and still getting the same error, it might be a server issue. Add this line at the beginning of your app/config/bootstrap.php file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

It's probably not the best solution, but it does the trick.

Comment: that's not how you do it in cakephp. It manages pretty mutch everything. you just have to specify Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8'); in config/core.php and have <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?> in your layout. Have 'encoding' => 'utf8' in your database array in config/database.php and use utf8 collate for tables and columns in your db.

Comment: Even when you have all the settings as you mention, the server can still override the setting of sending the file as UTF-8. That happened to me, the whole website was being served as ISO-8859-1 until I did that *ugly* trick to boostrap.php.As I said, it's not the best solution, but it does the trick.